# How to kill a MFC Thread

Tags: mfc

I create a thread :

```
static UINT MyThreadProc( void* pParam );
UINT CFTPDlg::MyThreadProc( void* pParam )  
{  
    CFTPDlg * pObject = (CFTPDlg *)pParam;
    pObject->buttonConnect();
    return 0;  
}
```

Then I start the thread using AfxBeginThread ( MyThreadProc, this);

How to delete my thread?

thanks a lot

Comment: The thread deletes itself when the thread proc returns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what buttonConnect does here. But the thread will exit automatically when buttonConnect returns.

You should be using pObject->DoModal() to actually see the dialog and work with it.

Re-think if you really need to create the UI in another thread.  If you want to show a dialog along with your main UI so that the user can access both your main UI & the dialog then you can opt for creating modeless dialog instead of creating a dialog in another thread.

If buttonConnect function is only connecting to another server, then you can create the UI in the main thread & spawn a thread to connect to the server.